# how to plot the difference of two Timelion time series alongside them

Tags: kibana, kibana-6, timelion

I have two long time series in timelion with different labels like `example1` and `example2`:

```
.es(q='(supported_version : true) && NOT (token : Alerter) && (upstream: example )').mvavg(window=1h).divide(.es(q='(supported_version : true) && NOT (token : Alerter)  && NOT (_exists_:(enriched)) && upstream: example').mvavg(window=1h)).label('example1').yaxis(units='percent',tickDecimals=2).precision(5).lines(show=true,fill=0.5, width=2)
```

I want to plot both of them plus their difference.

currently to achieve the difference bar I copy and paste both of them as follows:

```
(...first time series...).subtract(...second time series...)
```

but It's two long and messy.

how can I plot the difference without copy and pasting them? (e.g. using their labels or by assigning them to two variables if it's possible)

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: not yet (I think it's not possible till now).  FYI. there is a [Feature request](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/15545)- Variable assignment in Timelion on kibana github

Comment: Yeah, I came across that. That is quite useful for timelion charts.